# Функция заполняющая массив переменной длинны

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

Здравствуйте, решил сделать функцию которая бы заполняла массив строк переменной длины, не могу понять в чем проблемма, решение кажется простым.
Подскажите в чем моя ошибка и как правильно написать функцию по обработке массива переменной длины.

```
// description
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
void inputArrayString(int row, int col , std::string ar[row][col]);
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    const int Row = 3;
    const int Col = 4;

    string list2[Row][Col];
    inputArrayString(Row, Col, list2);
    return 0;
}
void inputArrayString(int row, int col , std::string ar[row][col])
{
    for (int r = 0; r < row; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < col; ++c)
            getline(std::cin, ar[r][c]);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Во первых вы могли бы сами почитать ошибки компиляции: вы в функции    задаете аргумент-размер и сразу же задаете массив с использованием    этого размера
p.s. а вдруг вы захотите заполнить не весь имеющийся массив...

Во вторых std::string это строка, и она может содержать очень много    количество слов, и `getline(std::cin, s);`  уже инициализирует    `string s` всей строкой, так что двумерный массив абсолютно не нужный    тип, а нужен просто массив строк

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
void inputArrayString(int row , std::string ar[]) 
{
    for (int c = 0; c < row; ++c) // тут вы уже устанавливаете количество 
             getline(std::cin, ar[c]); //инициализированных элементов массива           
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
int main()
{    
    using namespace std;
    const int row = 4;
    string list2[row];
    inputArrayString(row, list2);
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) // выводите список, для просмотра результата
    cout << list2[i] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```